# Unable to get the count of array using Javascript

Tags: javascript, count, element

I'm using this code and unable to get the count of elements in the `ls` below

```
var ls = new Array();
ls = document.getElementsByName(elx);
```

Comment: `getElementsByName()` accepts a string, but you have given it a variable whose definition we don't see. What is `elx`? You don't actually have any code here that checks the length of anything...

Comment: Is the problem that when you call ls.length you don't get a value?

Comment: I'm trying to call ls.count() and ls.length both are returning 0 only

Answer (score 2):

In javascript you can use .length to get a count of array...

Answer (score 2):

The number of elements are specified by the `length` property of the array returned by `getElementsByClassName`:

```
console.log( ls.length );
```

Answer (score 0):

Is elx a valid 'name' element in the document?

Comment: Note that you might get downvotes as this is a comment rather than an answer.

Comment: yes it is a valid input control

Comment: Just clarifying as a I don't see anything wrong with these lines of code

Answer (score 0):

This should give the number of elements returned by getElementsByName.

```
var ls = new Array();
ls = document.getElementsByName(elx);

count = ls.length;
```

If you are getting 0, it means you don't have any elements which has a name pointed by the variable elx.

Are you trying to do

```
ls = document.getElementsByName("elx");
```

which will return all elements with name "elx".